# Is this possible in jQuery date picker?

Tags: jquery-ui

Is this possible in jQuery date picker:

An inline date picker where I can use the next and previous buttons to cycle through months but choosing a particular day is disabled.

If so, please suggest a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes it is, you should invoke some options and methods of datepicker.
Take a look at the following functions:

[jquery ui datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) and search for:

- options: dateFormat (to specify your format)
- options: minDate and maxDate to specify the behavior of the widget. You can disable date older then now for example

Also take a look at the hooks in Events:

- beforeShow or onSelect.

To avoid the display of the Days part of the picker you could set the

```
table.ui-datepicker-calendar { display: none;}
```

Comment: when i try to use a negative number for minDate and maxDate, I observed that the days are already unclickable BUT the next and previous buttons as well! How can I resolve this?

Comment: I just tried it all on jsfiddle, and first disabled the ui as described above, the the next and previous are clickable. Just add a select button to the picker and hook into the datepicker methods to set the month and to invoke the select function. I just left out the max/minDate.

Comment: This is the scenario, I have an inline date picker that is fully enabled and an input field used as an alternate field for the date. I just want the alternate field to display the current date, unchangeable, no matter what I click on the inline date picker.

Answer (score 0):

> choosing a particular day is disabled.

Whats the point of disabling it, when u just need to make it look the same as other days? I think you can do that on any jQuery datePicker, even without this disabling select option, with just a little change of CSS:

```
td.selected, td.selected:hover, td.nonselected:hover {
  cursor: default;
  background: grey; /* use your datepicker background color */
}
```

Comment: This is the scenario, I have an inline date picker that is fully enabled and an input field used as an alternate field for the date. I just want the alternate field to display the current date, unchangeable, no matter what I click on the inline date picker.

Comment: i think it inputs data to an <input type="text" ...> right?
so why not set it's style="display:none;" and create new input with current date witch will be unaffected with datePicker?